# Xpath equivalent to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for Regex?

Tags: xml, xpath

I wonder if there is a Xpath equivalent to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for Regex?

In this way you could just type an xpath query and it will show you what elements were selected.

I haven't found anything as simple as http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ yet.

Comment: Since Nov. 2010 the XPath Visualizer has a new, safer home, kindly provided by Lars Huttar: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Some XPath visualisers

#### XPath applications

- [XPath Visualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/) -- Windows application, open source, requires .NET v. 3.5. Results shown as highlighted code. This is probably not the same tool that Dimitre already suggested although they have same name.
- [AquaPath](http://ditchnet.org/aquapath/) -- Macintosh application, open source. Results shown as highlighted code.

#### XML editors with somehow similar functionality

- [XMLMate](http://ditchnet.org/xmlmate/) -- Plugin to Macintosh application TextMate, open source.
- [Xmplify](http://xmplifyapp.com/) -- Macintosh application, still in beta.
- [Editix](http://editix.com/index.html) -- Cross platform application (Windows, Macintosh, Linux), requires Java 5.x or newer

#### Online services

- [Allans Online XPath Tester](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx) -- XML document can be pasted to textarea or referenced via URL. As a result prints the document contents with selected nodes highlighted below the textarea
- [XPath Query Expression Tool](http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx?mid=82) -- XML input via textarea. Doesn't actually highlight selection but prints the text content of selected elements
- Martijn van Beek's [XPath Analyser](http://martijnvanbeek.net/projects/xpath-analyser/) -- XML input via textarea, requires Flash, open source. **This is a new project: released 2010-08-24 so I'm guessing it will probably go through some updates or changes in the near future.**

#### Browser extensions (or something)

- [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1095/) -- Firefox extension. Shows an XPath query window instead of code highlight.
- [XPather](http://xpath.alephzarro.com/index) -- Firefox extension, requires DOM inspector extension.
- [XPath tester](http://www.shrinkrays.net/tools/xpath-tester.aspx) -- Requires Microsoft Silverlight

Comment: [1] The Oxygen XML editor <http://www.oxygenxml.com/> also does interactive xpath evaluation.
[2] There is a perl xpath command line script that comes with the Perl XPath module that will evaluate an xpath on a file and display the results.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Since Nov. 2010 the XPath Visualizer **[has a new, safer home](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**, kindly provided by Lars Huttar.

**Look up the** [**XPath Visualizer**](http://www.topxml.com/xpathvisualizer/) -- has [**versions for IE**](http://www.topxml.com/code/cod-422_10119_xpath-visualizer-14.aspx) and [**for Mozilla/Firefox**](http://www.topxml.com/code/cod-422_9827_xpath-visualizer-for-the-mozilla-browser.aspx)

This is a tool I wrote in 2000. Since then it has had many thousands of downloads and there hasn't been even a single unhappy user.

**Warning**: topxml.com has a trojan -- don't click on the above links unless you have a good malware protector.

Here are some screenshots from the tool, showing:

1. **The inline- hilighting of the selected nodes**
2. **Evaluating every possible XPath expression, not only those that select nodes**.
3. **Defining and using variables in the XPath expressions**.
4. **Remembering all used XPath expressions**.
5. **Defining and using XSLT keys**.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: How can i download it if it has a trojan? =)

Comment: btw, im using Mac, so i cant use Xpath Visualizer?

Comment: @ajsie: I don't think it will work on a Mac. It uses a browser and MSXML3. Maybe the version for Firefox will work on a Mac (haven't ever had a mac -- haven't ever tried).

As for how to download, if you send me email (my SO userid (dnovatchev) on the Google's mail), I will send you the files as attachment. Otherwise what I do is: 1. I download the file. 2. I clear the trojan with my anti-malware tool. I would be glad to give it for distribution on a more reliable host.

Comment: thanks. i have installed xpather on Firefox and it worked great.

Comment: @ajsie: I had a look at XPather and it seems to be very different, and in my opinion not so powerful and expressive as the XPath Visualizer. I have included in my answer a few screenshots from the XPath Visualizer, showing some of its features. So, you may judge for yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) is one I like using.

Paste in your XML, type your XPath expression and see what was selected.

It also has a pretty print options and an XSLT transformation option.

Answer (score 2):

[Xselerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator/) has an "XPath Query Analyser". Also it's a good IDE wich allow the use of many processors and viewers.

Answer (score 1):

I've got something like that on my xml tools page: http://www.flynn1179.net/xml/

Answer (score 0):

I have also made a online XPath evaluator. It supports both **XPath 1.0** and **XPath 2.0**. It is available here: [Online XPath Tester](http://www.xmltools.dk)

and here is a few screenshots:

XPath 2.0 evaluations which renders a sequence of numbers:

[image]

And, elements and attributes are marked when searched for:

[image]